# how to activate noise cancellation in sphinx4?

Tags: sphinx4, noise-reduction

There is a denoise.java file in  sphinx4/src/sphinx4/edu/cmu/sphinx/frontend/denoise
This file is not included in the frontend. So how should i activate this denoise.java so that noise cancellation gets activated in sphinx4.

Comment: denoise is included into frontend by default in latest version. You can check autocepstrum for details.

Comment: But in older version we have to explicitly include it.Now i have enabled the denoise.java but have anothe problem.The problem  is denoise works only with double precision wav files,but we always provide a single precision wav file .So do you know how to convert the single precision wav files to double precision wav files ??

Comment: I answered this question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29059287/how-to-reduce-noise-in-sphinx4-application/29062128#29062128