# How to disable noise cancellation in sphinx4-5prealpha?

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx, sphinx4, noise-reduction

I'm aware that static noise cancellation with spectral subtraction is enabled by default in latest version sphinx4-5prealpha, as was said in this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29062128/5534684

But there is some way of disable this feature and do not make any kind of noise reduction process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide `-remove_noise no` option in the [feat.params](https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinx4/blob/master/sphinx4-data/src/main/resources/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us/feat.params) file.